# Error when using a custom view location convention with Nancy's ConfigurableBootstrapper

Tags: nancy

I am using a subclass of *ConfigurableBootstrapper* to test my Nancy modules.  This is a workaround to get the ConfigurableBootstrapper to pick up the custom view location convention I use in the 'real' bootstrapper:

```
public class ConfigurableBootstrapperWithCustomConvention : ConfigurableBootstrapper
{
    public ConfigurableBootstrapperWithCustomConvention(Action<ConfigurableBootstrapperConfigurator> configuration)
        : base(configuration)
    {
    }

    protected override void ConfigureConventions(NancyConventions nancyConventions)
    {
        nancyConventions.ViewLocationConventions.Add((viewName, model, context) => 
            string.Concat(context.ModuleName, "/Views/", viewName));
        base.ConfigureConventions(nancyConventions);
    }
}
```

In my tests I first set the root path to that of my nancy project using the *FakeRootPathProvider*.  This contains the necessary folder structure ("/Home/Views/Index.cshtml") for the view used in *HomeModule* to be located *using this custom convention*.  The (simplified) test code:

```
[Test]
public void when_the_default_page_is_loaded_it_should_show_links_to_submit_form()
{
    FakeRootPathProvider.RootPath = "../../../MyApp.Web";

    var bootstrapper = new ConfigurableBootstrapperWithCustomConvention(with =>
    {
        with.RootPathProvider(new FakeRootPathProvider());
        with.ViewEngine<RazorViewEngine>();
        with.Module<HomeModule>();
    });

    var browser = new Browser(bootstrapper);
    var response = browser.Get("/");

    Assert.That(response.Body.AsString(), Is.StringContaining("<a href=\"SubmitSelf\">"));
}
```

When I run this test I get the following exception (at the call to *response.Body*):

```
System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: httpContext
   at System.Web.HttpContextWrapper..ctor(HttpContext httpContext)
   at System.Web.Optimization.Styles.RenderFormat(String tagFormat, String[] paths)
   at RazorOutput.RazorView.Execute()
   at Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.NancyRazorViewBase`1.ExecuteView(String body, IDictionary`2 sectionContents)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid3<T0,T1,T2>(CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
   at Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.RazorViewEngine.<>c__DisplayClass27.<RenderView>b__26(Stream stream)
   at Nancy.Testing.BrowserResponse.get_Body()
   at MyApp.Tests.Integration.Web.Home.HomeModuleTests.when_the_default_page_is_loaded_it_should_show_links_to_submit_form() in HomeModuleTests.cs: line 44
```

If I set the Fake root path to be "../../../MyApp.Web/Home/Views" instead, the test runs OK.  (**It appears that the custom view location convention is being ignored when testing using Nancy's "Browser" class**).

- Is there some issue with setting a NancyConvention in this way?
- If so is there a different way to set a view location convention with *ConfigurableBootstrapper*?

Comment: Did you manage to find the solution to this issue?

Comment: No unfortunately not - I get round it by setting the path to the views via the config file when I run my test fixture.